# Add 9 figures together (with one caption ) 3 in the same row and so on

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have an urgent question, I am new to Latex and I have to submit my thesis by tomorrow, I have been trying to add 9 figures together however, only 2 appears and the least not like they are on the border of the file , so even I want them top to each other, I had read some related answers.. nothing working

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.8\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{pics/"figure14_1"}
\caption{3-point bending}
\label{fig:figure14_1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering    
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{pics/"figure14_2"}
\caption{Elastic stress distribution}
\label{fig:figure14_2}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{pics/"figure14_3"}
\caption{Plastic stress distribution}
\label{fig:figure14_3}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pics/"figure14_4"}
\caption{Elastic shear stress distribution}
\label{fig:figure14_4}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pics/"figure14_5"}
\caption{Plastic shear stress distribution}
\label{fig:figure14_5}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pics/"figure14_6"}
\caption{Shaft under torsion}
\label{fig:figure14_6}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pics/"figure14_7"}
\caption{Elastic shear stress distribution}
\label{fig:figure14_7}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pics/"figure14_8"}
\caption{Plastic shear stress distribution}
\label{fig:figure14_8}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pics/"figure14_9"}
\caption{Linearly distributed load}
\label{fig:figure14_9}
\end{subfigure}%
    \caption{3-point bending, elastic and plastic stress distribution, shaft under torsion load and linearly distributed load.}
\label{figure14_99}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: "I am new to Latex" and "I have to submit my thesis by tomorrow"...what is wrong with this picture?  Welcome to the site.

Comment: your images are to wide to be fit in test width: (0.8+0.5+0.3+0.3+0.5+0.3+0.3+ ...)\text width ... please tell us, how if the width of images can be equal. also fore new line of images you need to insert empty line between rows in your editor.

Comment: @Zarko, Thank you so much, I have just tried it and it is working, however, there are some pics too huge and others two small. I do understand it depends on the width but actually I do know how to measure the width of the pics, I have mac and I am using preview to open the pics, I can edit the size but what you suggest me?
Also, it's perplexing to understand the meaning and the different of
line width here and text width...sometimes, when I play with these parameters, the caption are not centred. 
Again thank you so much and looking to hearing your reply.

Comment: (i) size of pictures in document: it your case they are determined with with width of `subfigure`s. in determining their widths you must care that sum of their widths in one line is smaller than text width; (ii) at different image size can happen that image hve different height. this can make problems with their vertical align; (iii) positioning of sub captions is depended from `subcaption` settings. as i see, now you use default settings (centered if is one line, justified if caption has more lines). the best is, if you can generate all your image with same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably you like to have the following arrangement of images:

[image]

I only cleaned up your code, removed all `\centering` instructions (they're not needed), corrected the widths of the `subfigure` environments, and inserted empty lines between each row of images:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pics/"figure14_1"}
\caption{3-point bending}
\label{fig:figure14_1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pics/"figure14_2"}
\caption{Elastic stress distribution}
\label{fig:figure14_2}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pics/"figure14_3"}
\caption{Plastic stress distribution}
\label{fig:figure14_3}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pics/"figure14_4"}
\caption{Elastic shear stress distribution}
\label{fig:figure14_4}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pics/"figure14_5"}
\caption{Plastic shear stress distribution}
\label{fig:figure14_5}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pics/"figure14_6"}
\caption{Shaft under torsion}
\label{fig:figure14_6}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pics/"figure14_7"}
\caption{Elastic shear stress distribution}
\label{fig:figure14_7}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pics/"figure14_8"}
\caption{Plastic shear stress distribution}
\label{fig:figure14_8}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pics/"figure14_9"}
\caption{Linearly distributed load}
\label{fig:figure14_9}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{3-point bending, elastic and plastic stress distribution, 
    shaft under torsion load and linearly distributed load.}
\label{figure14_99}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much!  it seems that i should repeat my first course of eng ... :-(