# How to fit six figures with different sizes?

Tags: graphics, floats, fit

I want to use pictures in the order below, how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us what you've tried so far (minimal, but compilable code example; MWE). You could e.g. use `subcaption` (if you want to have captions) or simple minipages or ...

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391242/add-9-figures-together-with-one-caption-3-in-the-same-row-and-so-on/391245#391245

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41166/vertically-align-different-size-images-in-a-figure-environment

Comment: If you know the widths, use a tabular with p{} columns.  IIRC, you can even use \subcaption in a p{} column.

Answer (score 2):

It's not difficult to achieve vertical centering of images with other methods, but `adjustbox` offers a simple interface.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\makebox[.33333\columnwidth]{%
  \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm,valign=c]{example-image}%
}%
\makebox[.33333\columnwidth]{%
  \includegraphics[width=4cm,height=3cm,valign=c]{example-image}%
}%
\makebox[.33333\columnwidth]{%
  \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm,valign=c]{example-image}%
}

\bigskip

\makebox[.33333\columnwidth]{%
  \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=1.5cm,valign=c]{example-image}%
}%
\makebox[.33333\columnwidth]{%
  \includegraphics[width=4cm,height=3cm,valign=c]{example-image}%
}%
\makebox[.33333\columnwidth]{%
  \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2cm,valign=c]{example-image}%
}

\caption{Six images}\label{foo}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]